jsTree - gembird's approach of lazy loading jsTree
There is implicitly typped array to be send to jsTree:
var first = new[]
{
new
{
    id = "Root " + i.ToString(),
    text = "Root Node " + i.ToString(),
    state = new
    {
        opened = true,
    },
    children = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            id = "Child " + gc1,
            text = "Child " + gc1,
            children = true
        },
        new
        {
            id = "Child " + gc2,
            text = "Child " + gc2,
            children = true
        }
    }
}
}
.ToList();

It works great.
enter image description here
But it does not work, when i try to declare the child in code above and add it to first parent:
var child = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                id = "Child " + gc1,
                text = "Child " + gc1,
                children = true
            }
        }
.ToArray();


var first = new[]
{
new
{
    id = "Root " + i.ToString(),
    text = "Root Node " + i.ToString(),
    state = new
    {
        opened = true,
    },
    children = new[]
    {
        child
    }
}
}
.ToList();

enter image description here
What am I doing wrong, why jsTree does not display the child in this case, please?
Thnx!!!
I tried to compare both JsonResults and it seems to be the same...

Adding two types helped to solve this:
public class rodic
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string text { get; set; }
public string icon { get; set; }
public object state { get; set; }
public List children { get; set; }
}
public class decko
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string text { get; set; }
public string icon { get; set; }
public object state { get; set; }
public bool children { get; set; }
}
....

and then
And then
nodesDecko.Add(new decko { id = dite.id, text = dite.text, icon=ikonaDite, children = dite.children });
nodesRodic.Add(new rodic { id = objectKey.ToString(), text = objectKey + " " + "[" + objectType + "] " + nameJIRA, icon = "/images/icons/" + iconName, state = new { opened = true }, children = nodesDecko });

Adding two classes helped to solve this:
public class rodic
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public object state { get; set; }
    public List<decko> children { get; set; }
}


public class decko
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public object state { get; set; }
    public bool children { get; set; }
}

and then
nodesDecko.Add(new decko { id = dite.id, text = dite.text, icon=ikonaDite, children = dite.children });
nodesRodic.Add(new rodic { id = objectKey.ToString(), text = objectKey + " " + "[" + objectType + "] " + nameJIRA, icon = "/images/icons/" + iconName, state = new { opened = true }, children = nodesDecko });

